# Question over Nodes of Runge-Kutta methods

Tags: runge-kutta-methods, quadrature

I have (hopefully) an easy question.

Suppose I have the following system (derived from an integration)

$I'(t)= f(t), \, t \in [0,\pi]\\
I(0)=0$

My goal is to find $I(\pi)= \int_{0}^{\pi}f(t) \text{d}t$ using a RK method on the differential setting.

Since $f$ does not depend on $I$, a RK method of size $m \geq1$ can be described only through the vectors $b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Suppose we divide $[0,\pi]$ into a collection of equidistant $N_{t}>1$ points. We then have $\Delta t = \frac{\pi}{N_{t}-1}$ This means $t_{k}=k \Delta t $ for $k \in \lbrace 0, \ldots, N_{t}-1\rbrace$.

A single step of Runge Kutta reads:
\begin{align}
I^{k+1}-I^{k}= \Delta t \sum_{i=1}^{m} b_{i} f(t_{k}+c_{i} \Delta t)
\end{align}
summing over all $N_{t}$ points we get
\begin{align}
I^{N_{t}}-I^{0} = \sum_{k=0}^{N_{t}-1}(I^{k+1}-I^{k}) =\sum_{k=0}^{N_{t}-1} \Delta t \sum_{i=1}^{m} b_{i} f(t_{k}+c_{i} \Delta t)
\end{align}

By assumption $I(0)=0$ so that we obtain \begin{align}
I^{N_{t}} = \Delta t \sum_{k=0}^{N_{t}-1} \sum_{i=1}^{m} b_{i} f(t_{k}+c_{i} \Delta t)
\end{align}

Up to here everything is reasonable in my mind. But then I encounter problems when a $c$ contains an entry bigger or equal than one.
For example here's Heun's method $c =(0, \, 1); b = (\frac{1}{2}, \, \frac{1}{2})$.

We then have for calculating $I^{N_{t}}$
\begin{align}
I^{N_{t}} = \frac{\Delta t}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{N_{t}-1} [ f(t_{k})+f(t_{k+1})]
\end{align}
consider now only the last summand that is $$f(t_{N_{t}-1})+f(t_{N_{t}}).$$

Here's my problem: While $t_{N_{t}-1}$ is a well defined point in our $t-$grid, $t_{N_{t}}$ is not.
Now since $f$ is given and can be computed even on nodes outside of those considered, this should not arise any questions. Anyway I was wondering if having nodes outside of the "chosen" ones is a problem or not.

I apologize for any language related problems, unfortunately English is not my mother tongue.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: See composite trapezoidal method. In what sense is $t_{N_t}=\pi$ outside the interval $[0,\pi]$? Many RK methods have $c_s=1$, so this kind of duplicate use of function values is not a rarity. Note that quadrature methods in general have more flexibility than explicit RK methods with the same number of nodes, so with the same number of stages/nodes one can achieve a higher order. See the Gauss quadrature methods. (These have counterparts in implicit Gauss RK methods.)

Comment: Yes, this can be confounding. You are or were defining the subdivision for $N_t$ points, but were doing the summation for $N_t$ segments. For a summation over the correct amount of $N_t-1$ segments, the upper bound for the sums has to be $N_t-2$.

Comment: Sorry I misclicked multiple times and couldn't get the message written... It is indeed what you say. For sake of completeness I still post what I tried to type.
I guess I found my error. I stated that:
"Summing over the $N_{t}$ points we have" \begin{align}
I^{N_{t}} = \sum^{N_{t}-1}
\end{align}
but that should be wrong since i have indexed $k \in \lbrace 0, \ldots, N_{t}-1 \rbrace$.
I am instead searching for \begin{align}
I^{N_{t}-1}= \sum^{N_{t}-2}.
\end{align}
Now I have no problem since $t_{N_{t}-2}+c_{i}\Delta t \leq t_{N_{t}-1$}.

Thanks a lot!